# how to set bépo layout for cryptsetup

Tags: keyboard

i want to enter my password for cryptsetup (ubuntu 19.04) only with my bépo keyboard,
how can i achieve cryptsetup to understand that ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/vconsole.conf` as an admin and add:

```
KEYMAP=fr-bepo
```

Afterwards, save it, and it will be OK for cryptsetup.

Reference: https://bepo.fr/wiki/Console_GNU/Linux